# I am shipping paintings from my house in CA to my house in Verona, Italy

Tags: italy, shipping

If I ship household goods (paintings) do I have to pay tax? I was told by the agency crating that I have to pay import tax (IVA) plus customs fees. True?  Has anyone found a reasonable air shipping agent for a 4 ft x 4 ft x 1 ft wide.

Comment: You can pop the paintings off the frame, roll them up, put them in a tube, and hand carry them. Then you can reframe (or have them reframed) them in Italy.  Feasibility depends a bit on the details, but in many cases that's the cheapest and safest approach.  Crating paintings safely is a bit of art since you need to manage temperature and humidity even for air shipping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's true.  Household goods are exempt from fees if you are moving your residence, but not if you are transferring them to or from a secondary residence.

Depending on the value of the paintings, it may make more sense to take them with you as oversize baggage when you fly.  The maximum size is 115 inches, summing length, width, and height; a 4x4x1 package is 108 inches.  The personal customs exemption is €430 for air and sea travelers.